# How can some enzymes work faster than the diffusion rates of the molecules it catalyzes allow?

Tags: enzyme-kinetics

Quoting Wikipedia: ["Some enzymes operate with kinetics which are faster than diffusion rates, which would seem to be impossible."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_limited_enzyme#Mechanism) Which are those enzymes and how can they be so fast?

One example is catalase which [Lionel Milgrom discusses in Water Journal no. 7](https://www.waterjournal.org/volume-7/milgrom).

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No. I ask since some surfing didn't give any answer.

Comment: Diffusion rates of what? Please provide some explanation in your question. As it is now, the question is unclear.

Comment: What is the source of your assertion?

Comment: @WYSIWYG I presume he's referring to [diffusion-controlled reactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion-controlled_reaction) and [diffusion limited enzymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_limited_enzyme). It's a rather standard concept in enzyme kinetics.

Comment: @David [Here](http://sandwalk.blogspot.com/2012/05/better-biochemistry-perfect-enzyme.html) is one such claim: "One of these enzymes, superoxide dismutase, actually catalyzes reactions FASTER than the diffusion-controlled rate. That's because the active site is surrounded by charged residues that attract oppositely charged substrate molecules!"

Comment: OK. Now we know what you are talking about. I can't imagine there are many more — there's obviously something about the chemistry that allows the enzyme to develop such an extreme kcat.  I imagine you need to surf kcat to find others. Not many of us have a "Guinness Book of Records"  mindset.

Comment: Here is one article trying to explain why catalase is faster than diffusion rates allow. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316504611_Why_is_catalase_do_fast . Please open this question.

Comment: Is this more of a chemistry question? I asked the same question in Stack Exchange Chemistry without reactions: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/118608/how-can-some-enzymes-work-faster-than-the-diffusion-rates-of-the-reactants-allow